# Post-increment and retro compatibility

Tags: php, oop

I have an example where I can't figure out why the result is not what I expect.

Code:

```
class A
{
    protected $a = 1;

    function a(){
        echo $this->a++;
    }
}

class B extends A
{
    protected $a = 10;

    function b(){
        echo $this->a++; $this->a() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$b = new B();
$b->b();
```

In my mind the max that I could expect from the result would be like 1011, but it looks like the result is 10111213. I can't figure out why I'm getting this result. Can someone explain to me what is going under the hood?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because your methods have the same name (case insensitive) as the classes that contain them. They're behaving like [constructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php) as well as your explicit calls.

From the PHP documentation I linked above:

> For backwards compatibility with PHP 3 and 4, if PHP cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

So `$b = new B();` produces 1011, and `$b->b();` produces 1213.

This behavior is deprecated, and you'll get a warning to that effect if you have that level of error reporting enabled. I see this message in my dev environment:

> Deprecated: Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; A has a deprecated constructor in C:\Apache24\htdocs\example.php on line 2

Obviously the easiest way to avoid the unexpected behavior is to change the name of the methods to something other than the class name. If you don't want to do that, you can add a modern constructor.

```
function __construct() {}
```

Even if it doesn't actually do anything else, it will stop the `a()` and `b()` methods from acting like constructors.